# Delaying code execution

Tags: pascal

I'm a 10 grader who loves programming and im currently enjoying pascal code.
I want to know if it is possible to delay the appearance of certain lines like:

```
begin

writeln('I''m awesome');
readln;

end.
```

is it possible to make the text appear only after 5 seconds for example?
Thanks.

Comment: What version of Pascal are you using, and on what operating system?

Comment: When learning and writing in a programming language, documentation is your friend. Look up "delay" or "sleep" library functions. The Pascal you are using might have them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/sleep.html

add

```
Sleep(5000);
```

The time in the sleep is in milliseconds

1 second = 1000 milliseconds

your code would look like:

```
begin

  Sleep(5000);
  writeln('I''m awesome');
  readln;

end.
```